# Structures of Inderminate Length

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, console

I am trying to understand Structures. Here is what I have

```
Structure Tbook
    Dim ISBN As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Price As Double
    Dim YearOfPub As Integer
End Structure
Dim books(2) As Tbook
```

Seems simple enough. I then try to populate it. However, I used a While Loop because I don't necessary want to fill it with 3 records. Instead I want to choose when to terminate data entry. Lets pretend I add 1 record not 3

```
Sub myStructure()
    Dim answer As Char
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < 2
        Console.WriteLine("Enter details")
        Console.WriteLine("ISBN : ")
        books(i).ISBN = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Title : ")
        books(i).Title = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Price : ")
        books(i).Price = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Year of Publication : ")
        books(i).YearOfPub = Console.ReadLine()
        i = i + 1
        If i < 2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Add another book? Y/N")
            answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper
            If answer = "N" Then
                i = 3
            End If
        End If
    End While
```

Finally, I want to print out what I have. I have used a For Loop here which is obviously wrong. This code will print out 3 records but in my example - only 1 of these will have data.

```
For i = 0 To 2
        Console.WriteLine("==================================")
        Console.WriteLine("ISBN : " & books(i).ISBN)
        Console.WriteLine("Title : " & books(i).Title)
        Console.WriteLine("Price : " & books(i).Price)
        Console.WriteLine("Year of Publication : " & books(i).YearOfPub)
        Console.WriteLine("==================================")
        Console.WriteLine("")
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

Piddling around with code like this leaves me with a few questions which may help others

a) Is it possible to create a structure of indeterminate size?

b) If not must you always 'fill' a structure with records

c) If you can 'partially fill' one, how do you print just these records

Many thanks to anyone with patience to explain this to me (and hopefully others)

Comment: You need to take a look at [List(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If instead of an array, you used a `List(of TBook)` your code could only add complete/whole books to it.  You might want to read [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx).  If you wanted to display the items in a List control (or DGV), a struct with fields would require a lot of extra work.  BTW neihter the structure or array re of indeterminate length - you just might not have any data in some elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code rewritten to use a generic `List(Of TBook)`

```
' This should be declared at the global level if you want to use'
' it everywhere in this class or module.'
Dim books As List(Of Tbook) = new List(Of Tbook)

Sub myStructure()
    Dim answer As Char
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While True 
        Dim book As Tbook
        Console.WriteLine("Enter details")
        Console.WriteLine("ISBN : ")
        book.ISBN = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Title : ")
        book.Title = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Price : ")
        Dim input  = Console.ReadLine()
        Double.TryParse(input, book.Price)
        Console.WriteLine("Year of Publication : ")
        book.YearOfPub = Console.ReadLine()
        books.Add(book)
        Console.WriteLine("Add another book? Y/N")
        answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper
        If answer = "N" Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Here instead of having an array of fixed size you have a variable of type `List(Of TBook)` and you could Add a TBook inside a loop until you stop the input loop.

Notice that being `TBook` a structure you don't need to allocate a new element at each loop but you could add it directly to the list. Finally take care on the input of the Price field. It is a double and assigning it directly from the ReadLine that return a string is something to be avoided. You have [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to Off otherwise this code could not be compiled.

Of course reading from a List(Of TBook) is

```
For Each book In books
    Console.WriteLine("==================================")
    Console.WriteLine("ISBN : " & book.ISBN)
    Console.WriteLine("Title : " & book.Title)
    Console.WriteLine("Price : " & book.Price)
    Console.WriteLine("Year of Publication : " & book.YearOfPub)
    Console.WriteLine("==================================")
    Console.WriteLine("")
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it took me awhile to respond - I wanted to understand your response and read up on List(Of T).  This has given me much to think about and a superb springboard for further learning. Most appreciated!

Comment: @ Steve Hi Steve, I seem to have a problem implementing your suggestion. I keep the structure I made at the top of my code and then replace what I had with the new code you very kindly wrote. However, VB has a problem with any line that includes the word 'books' as in 'books.Add(book)' and For Each book In Books. The error reads 'books is not declared'. I must be doing some rather stupid.

Comment: Missing the declaration of books. Fixing now

Comment: @ Steve. Thank you soooo much. I spent all evening trying to figure out how to fix this! I did try this: Dim books As List(Of Tbook) but didn't work for me as I missed the :new List(Of Tbook). What does 'new List(Of Tbook)' do.....sorry to test your patience

Comment: The Dim ... simply declares the variable and its type. But this is a reference variable not a simple integer, string or decimal. A reference variable needs to be allocated (meaning an area of memory should be reserved for the object represented by the variable) so VB.NET (and C#) have this operator New that is followed by the type thus giving to the compiler the required information on how much memory is required

Comment: Thank you. This has been extremely helpful.  Lots of research avenues for me and a great basis to start experimentation! I really, really appreciate your support